# Openlayers 3 Offset RegularShape

Tags: openlayers-3

For clustered features I would like to make the following style in OL3:

A square, and on top of it another smaller square at the right-top corner. The bigger square would hold the symbol, and the smaller square would hold the number of the clustered features.

Similar to [this](http://www4.pcmag.com/media/images/354486-instagram-photo-maps.jpg?thumb=y)

Is it possible to achieve this? In the API I've seen that ol.style.Icon and ol.style.Text has anchor and offset properties, but not RegularShape...

Answer (score 1):

I have eventually overcome on this problem with using a single png image which included the square AND the smaller square, too, and overlayed the dynamic text on it, like this:

```
    var clusterStyle = [new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
          src: clustericon.png
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          text: feature.get('features').length.size.toString(),
          offsetY: -18,
          offsetX: 18,
          font: '12px Arial',
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#fff'
          }),
          scale: 1
        }),
        zIndex: 20
      }), new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
          src: 'overlayicon.png'
        }),
        zIndex: 21
      })];
```

You can also insert an overlay image on it. Hope it helps you anyways